# How to refresh another page in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So here:

I want to refresh page A but the refresh will trigger on page B. Is is any other way where it's not from the localstorage?

Because I'm working on an e-commerce website. And I want page A to refresh when a button on page B is clicked. So that the content of page A will be updated just like in page B.

To understand more:

page A is the order details screen for the customer or client
page B is the order details screen for the partner or seller

So the idea is, when the partner/seller updated the order status (on the way, in the kitchen, complete) from page B, the page A will refresh so that the customer or client will see their updated order status.

I hope that makes sense. A help is really much appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: To refresh the page I'm assuming you are supposed to change the state of some contents, I suggest you to exploring Redux and Context API from React.js

Answer (score 0):

The scenario is pretty much like having an admin page and a client page. When updating status of a product's status from the admin page, we want to also update that of in the Client page.

I think you can use firebase/firestore:
In the admin page you can update the document of a collection, for example product

```
const productRef = db.collection('product').doc('id_1');

const res = await productRef.set({
  status: "active"
}, { merge: true });
```

In the client site, we can listen change on that collection's document
For example:

```
firestore().collection('product').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
// handle changes to documents in the collection here
})
```

By doing that it solves a bigger problem where user can be any browser or devices...